# pandas dataframe has date stored as datetime64[ns] but putting unique values into a list give a cryptic long integer

Tags: python, pandas, list, datetime

let's say when i type df.dtypes it returns

```
Name               int64
UpdateTime         datetime64[ns]
EnquiryDate        datetime64[ns]
dtype: object

ls_UpdateDate = df['UpdateTime'].sort_values().unique().tolist()

print(ls_UpdateDate)
```

give me

```
[1570492800000000000,
 1570665600000000000,
 1571097600000000000,
 1571270400000000000,
 1571356800000000000,
 1571616000000000000,
 1571788800000000000,
 1571875200000000000,
 1572480000000000000]
```

What can i do to get the list as just a normal date format, without the h,m,s

Thanks in advance!

Comment: thanks U10-Forward for the edit, was about to do it and you did it for me

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time Look at `pd.to_datetime`